# 401 Unauthorized when try to call office 365 API with an obtained access token

Tags: java, azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Java to create a simple daemon or service app (not Web app) to call an Office 365 Calendar API. I've followed this guide [Call Microsoft Graph in a service or daemon app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/app_only), but when I try to call the API with the access token, I obtain a 401 error.
I've registered the app to azure portal with all the Graph authorizations and I've made the certificate, following the Step 1 of this guide: [Get a certificate or create a self-signed certificate](http://www.nubo.eu/en/blog/2016/11/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-create-a-deamon-application-for-office365/). Here is my code for the access token request:`

```
    String accessToken="";
    String token_endpoint = "https://login.windows.net/<mytenant>/oauth2/token";
    String grant_type = "client_credentials";
    String client_secret = <mysecret>;
    String resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
    String client_id = <myclient>;

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(token_endpoint);
    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", grant_type));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", client_id));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", client_secret));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("resource", resource));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost)) {
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        //parsing
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Scanner httpResponseScanner = new Scanner(entity.getContent());
        String jsonString = httpResponseScanner.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(jsonString);
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);
        accessToken = json.get("access_token").toString();

        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    }
    return accessToken;`
```

And here is my API call code:`

```
     String apiURL = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars";
     CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
     HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(apiURL);
     httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
     httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

     try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet)) {
         System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         EntityUtils.consume(entity);
     }`
```

I've already tested my access token to jwt.io with invalid signature response, so I think there is something wrong in my token request. Someone can help me?

Comment: If the token is valid, it should contain the names of the permissions given on the Microsoft Graph API, as well as mentioning the audience as Microsoft Graph. Check the permissions you granted are in the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code , you are acquiring token for resource :https://graph.microsoft.com , but in api calls with that token , you are calling the outlook mail rest api (https://outlook.office.com/) . If you want to call microsoft graph api (https://graph.microsoft.com ) , you should check the [microsoft graph api get calendars](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendars) .

The second problem is you are using client credential flow (app's identity) , you can't use user identity (`/me`) because there is no user information includes in access token . With microsoft graph api , you could use `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars`

Comment: Thank you a lot, I change the URL of the get request with this https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user principal name>/calendars and it works.